# React export Excel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to give an array to the data part of the excel table. How can I do it ?
This is my code:

```
filteredData() {

    for (const row of this.props.processes) {
      const values = allverbisheaders.map((header) => {
        return row[header];
      });
      this.state.CSVRows.push(values);
    }
    console.log(this.state.CSVRows[0]);
    console.log(this.state.CSVRows[1]);
    console.log(this.state.CSVRows[2]);
    console.log(this.state.CSVRows[3]);
    return this.state.CSVRows;
  };


const VerbisSet = [
  {
      columns: [
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[0], width: {wch: 27}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[1], width: {wch: 20}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[2], width: {wch: 33}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[3], width: {wch: 30}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[4], width: {wch: 30}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[5], width: {wch: 30}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[6], width: {wch: 30}},
          {title: allverbisheaderstr[7], width: {wch: 30}},
      ],
      data: [
        [
          this.state.CSVRows[0]
        ],
       ]
  }
];



 return (
  <div>

    <DropdownItem
      onClick ={() => {this.filteredData()}}>
      Process Listesi Kontrol
    </DropdownItem>

    <DropdownItem>
    <ExcelFile element={<a>Verbis</a>}>
      <ExcelSheet dataSet={VerbisSet} name="Verbis Data"/>
    </ExcelFile>
    </DropdownItem>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

CSVRow is a matrix. And the first element is:

```
(8) ["Education", "Learning Information", "Education Status", "CONTRACT", "E", "E", "Employee", "EMAIL - HAND"]
```

I want to add this matrix to Excel table.

I pre-run the filteredData function and set the CSVRows matrix.

Comment: Are you using the library `react-export-excel`? It seems that it doesn't support setting the cell width.

Comment: I am using the react-data-Export library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure about the shape of your data, but I suspect the issue is due to the dimensions of the data.

From the library's document, the length of the `data` field should match the length of the `columns` field. However, your `data` field has a length of 1, while the length of `columns` is 8.

Try the following:

```
const VerbisSet = [
  {
    columns: [
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[0], width: { wch: 27 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[1], width: { wch: 20 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[2], width: { wch: 33 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[3], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[4], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[5], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[6], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[7], width: { wch: 30 } },
    ],
    data: [
      // notice here, I removed one level of array nesting
      this.state.CSVRows[0]
    ],
  }
];
```

Or simply like this:

```
const VerbisSet = [
  {
    columns: [
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[0], width: { wch: 27 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[1], width: { wch: 20 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[2], width: { wch: 33 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[3], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[4], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[5], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[6], width: { wch: 30 } },
      { title: allverbisheaderstr[7], width: { wch: 30 } },
    ],
    data: this.state.CSVRows,
  }
];
```

Comment: The problem was in the array I gave as data. As a workaround I changed this.state.CSVRows to the appropriate type. Thanks for the solution you gave :)